# laravel Cannot use Positional Argument after Named argument

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to using Laravel, and am a bit confused by this error. I am inside of my Home Controller and am trying to display the data from my database. However, I got this error: cannot use positional argument after named argument. Has anyone come accross this error? I use VScode.

Here is the code that I have:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $allCategories = ['Category 1', 'Category 2'];

        return view(view: 'index', ['categories' => $allCategories]);
    }
}
```

Edit: the error is only on the return view line

Comment: `return view('index', ['categories' => $allCategories]);` or `return view(view: 'index', data: ['categories' => $allCategories]);` - You can't mix and match named (`view: ...`) and positional (`, [...]`, without a name, `data:`, etc.) arguments.

Comment: try use this as your return statement return view('index', ['categories' => $allCategories]);